# How to add all product amount in reactjs which is coming from api

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am fetching cart data from api which look something like this

[image: cartimage]

and I am trying to add totaAmount of all the product to display on different component Which i am unable to figure out.

I component I have maped all the data like this.

```
{props.cartList &&  props.cartList.map((item) => {

  return <Product
            productImage={item.image._links.mainImage.href}
            productName = {item.productName}
            productAmount = {item.totalAmount}
            productQuantity={item.totalQuantity}
            productId = {item.productId}
        />
})}

<br />
<TopTitle left="Deliver This To" />
<Address address={props.address} />
<TopTitle left="Change" />
<Coupon />
<TopTitle left="T-money" />
<DetailRow details={"Current T-Money"} price={"₹ 34,536   "} />
<Coupon />
<TopTitle left="Order Summary" />
<DetailRow
  details={"Total MRP (Inclusive of all taxes)"}
  price={"₹ 999"}
/>
```

Here I want to pass the `totalAmount` to the `<DetailRow />` component inside price.

Comment: Why not move `DetailRow` inside `map`?

Comment: @UtsavPatel I think OP wants the total of _all_ products in the cart. Or. Maybe not. I'm not sure what OP is asking here. You could compute the grand total with `const total = props.cartList.reduce(( total, {totalAmount, totalQuantity}) => (total + (totalAmount * totalQuantity)), 0)`.

Comment: @rayhatfield In that case, he should just do a `reduce` on `totalAmount`, when he is fetching/computing `cartList`.

Comment: Right. Updated my comment. Reading the question again I'm not sure what OP is asking here.

Comment: @UtsavPatel yeah u are right i want to display total amount in in cart for that i need to pass total amount to DetailRow to display it.